# How to change default html tag rendering in Orchard?

Tags: html, content-management-system, themes, orchardcms

I have theming enabled and Orchard renders the page like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="de-DE" class="static dir-ltr dennree-tuesdaymail" dir="ltr"> 
<head> 
  <meta ...
```

but i need it to be rendered like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="de" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="de" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="de" xml:lang="de">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta ...
```

I didn't find any way to adjust the html tag rendering in the Layout.cshtml of a Orchard theme.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `Document.cshtml` in your Theme.

```
@using Orchard.Mvc.Html;
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;
@{
    RegisterLink(new LinkEntry {Type = "image/x-icon", Rel = "shortcut icon", Href = Url.Content("~/modules/orchard.themes/Content/orchard.ico")});
    Script.Include("html5.js").UseCondition("lt IE 9").AtHead();

    string title = Convert.ToString(Model.Title);
    string siteName = Convert.ToString(WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName);
}
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="@WorkContext.CurrentCulture" class="static @Html.ClassForPage()"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title> 
    @Display(Model.Head)
    <script>        (function (d) { d.className = "dyn" + d.className.substring(6, d.className.length); })(document.documentElement);</script> 
</head> 
<body>
@* Layout (template) is in the Body zone @ the default position (nothing, zero, zilch) *@
@Display(Model.Body)
@Display(Model.Tail)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, now i can customize the whole page as needed.

Comment: What's the significance of that `~/modules/orchard.themes` in the `Url.Content` call above? Can't it just be omitted; i.e. is the path resolved for the current theme, falling back to the root application path (as described e.g. here http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Themes-includes/#htmlregisterstylesheet )?